# Is it incorrect to use "belong" as an auxiliary verb?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Say I used the sentence:

> We belong doing this.

In this case, *belong* would be the auxiliary verb, similar to *should* or *ought to be*, and *doing* would be the full verb.

Is this incorrect, or simply an uncommon use of the word?

Comment: This is not a feature of any standard English, but it does occur in several English-based creole languages (like Tok Pisin in New Guinea), where _belong_ -- spelt as _bilong_ or _blong_ -- is used as an auxiliary of several types, indicating possession, subordination, and continuous aspect, among other things.

Comment: It would be good to add a few examples from the internet, which might be expected to exist, given John's statement.

Answer (score 2):

Per the *Oxford Modern English Grammar* by Bas Aarts, there's a NICE answer to this question:

- **N** is for negation. Can we negate *belong* with a contraction the way we can with other auxiliaries?

  > We did**n't** do this.
  >   ***** We belong**n't** doing this.
- **I** is for inversion. Can we switch verb and subject?

  > Did we do this?
  >   ***** Belong we do this?
- **C** is for code. Can we strand the verb in a later part of the sentence and have it carry the meaning from an earlier part?

  > We can do this, and so **can** they.
  >   ***** We belong do this, and so **belong** they.
- **E** is for emphasis. Can we add force to the verb for effect?

  > We most certainly *did* do that!
  >   ***** We most certainly *belong* do that!

Zero for four. *Belong* is not an auxiliary.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize there was this rule. 

I just noticed in the Merriam-Webster online definition that it's a _verbal_ auxiliary. As the other answer implies, this remains colloquial. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In comments, John Lawler wrote:

> This is not a feature of any standard English, but it does occur in several English-based creole languages (like Tok Pisin in New Guinea), where *belong* -- spelt as *bilong* or *blong* -- is used as an auxiliary of several types, indicating possession, subordination, and continuous aspect, among other things.