# Is helped a helping verb?

Tags: verbs

In the sentence "She helped build the house." Is the verb "helped build" where "helped" is a helping verb?

Similarly, in the sentence "I helped discover tombs of pharaohs." is the verb "helped discover?" here "helped" is a helping verb?

Comment: Which definition of "helping verb" are you using?

Comment: While helpful, *help* is not an auxiliary “helping” verb; it’s a [catenative verb](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-catenative-verb-1689832)

Comment: Helped build" is not a single verb but two lexical verbs. In your example "She helped build the house", "helped" is a **catenative** verb and the subordinate clause "build the house" is its catenative complement. Incidentally, I strongly advise you to drop the term "helping verb". It's a misnomer and quite inappropriate.

Comment: The *question* isn't quite a duplicate, but [this answer to an earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/353118/470858) should settle the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I never knew the term "catenative verb"; I learned the term "helping verb" back in grade school some 30 years ago. #TIL. This verb was used in a LSAT prep question and the author of the question said "helped" was the verb and didn't ascribe a part of speech to "build".

Comment: Followup question: What about the sentence: The apprentice helped the master builder build the house. Would the verb of that sentence still be "helped build" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a comment BillJ wrote:

> "Helped build" is not a single verb but two lexical verbs. In your example "She helped build the house", "helped" is a **catenative** verb and the subordinate clause "build the house" is its catenative complement. Incidentally, I strongly advise you to drop the term "helping verb". It's a misnomer and quite inappropriate.